# c# - ASP.NET MVC4 HtmlHelper Not rendering html

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-mvc-4

Im trying to create an Html Helper that renders blog posts from a database, but for some reason the HtmlHelper doesn't render the code..

This is what my helper looks like:

```
@helper Render(System.Web.Mvc.HtmlHelper html, T2L.Models.Post post, bool isAdmin, bool isMember)
{
    <p>dsfds</p>
    <div class="wrapper_top">
        <div class="grid_1 alpha">
            <div class="date">
                <span>
                    @post.time.ToString("MMM").ToUpper()

                </span>
                @post.time.ToString("dd")
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="content span_2_of_single">
            <h5 class="blog_title"><a href="@Href("~/Blog/p/" + post.id)">@post.title</a></h5>
            <div class="content">
                <div class="span-1-of-1">
                    <a href="bloginner.html"><img class="m_img"  src="@post.thumbnail" alt=""/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="span-1-of-2">
                    <p>@post.body</p>

                    <a href="@Href("~/Blog/p/"+post.id)" class="arrow_btn">Read More</a>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>  
            <div class="links">
                <h3 class="comments">By<a href="bloginner.html">@post.author</a></h3>
                <h3 class="comments"><a href="#">10 Comments</a></h3>
                <h3 class="tags">Tags: <a href="#">Design</a>,<a href="#">Creative</a>,<a href="#">wordpress theme</a></h3>
                <h3>Share</h3>
                <h3>
                    <div class="social_1">
                        <ul>    
                            <li class="icon1_t"><a href="#"><span> </span></a></li>
                            <li class="icon2_f"><a href="#"><span> </span></a></li>     
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </h3>
                <div class="clear"> </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clear"> </div>
    </div>
}
```

and this is how I call it:

```
   @if (Model.Count() == 0)
                {
                    <div class="wrapper_top">
                        <p style="font-size:22px; font-weight:bold; font-style:italic; color:#1d7abc;">No posts available..</p>
                    </div>
                }
                else
                {
                    foreach (Post post in Model)
                    {
                        PostGenerator.Render(Html, post, isAdmin, isMember);
                    }
                }
```

I don't see what I'm doing wrong exactly.. 
Can someone please help??

Comment: that's not usually how you make an HtmlHelper.  Usually it's an extension method off an `HtmlHelper` object.  It looks like what you're trying to do is define a _Section_ or perhaps a _Partial View_

Comment: That's a View Helper indeed.

Comment: Yeah its a view helper, but it wont render.. i had it working a while ago but idk am i doing something wrong??

Comment: You're missing the `@` as @Floremin already answered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try adding `@` in front of your call:

```
@PostGenerator.Render(Html, post, isAdmin, isMember)
```

Comment: Sweeet! That did the trick! lol thw power of the "At" Symbol!